# how to write a string to a file that contains html tags

Tags: php, html, file-io

I have created new .php file through php file system and now I am trying to write html code into file. Here is the code

```
        $file = 'django unchained.php';
        if($handle = fopen($file , 'a'))
        {
            $text = htmlentities("<a href=\"index.php\">Just link</a>");
            echo $text; // here it shows up fine in webpage.
            file_put_contents($file , $text); // after writing to file it doesnot appear the same in .php file
            fclose($handle);    
        }
```

As mentioned in comment above when I echo it in webpage it shows up fine but doesnot appear the same when same string is written to file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't appear the same", how does it appear?

Comment: You're unnecessarily mixing fopen/fclose with file_put_conents. Use one or the other.

Comment: You probably see `&lt;a...&gt;` and so on, right? That's caused by `htmlentities()`. Write the raw text into the file.

Comment: Yes &lt;a...&gt; appeared. But without htmlentities() it didn't appear in file that I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the source code of your HTML page, you'll see the same text, you see in `django unchained.php`:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;index.php&quot;&gt;Just link&lt;/a&gt;
```

This text is generated by [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function, that converts special HTML characters to their entity equivalents. This behaviour is absolutely predictable and correct.

If you want to output to file the unquoted text, do this:

```
<?php
$file = 'django unchained.php';
$text = "<a href=\"index.php\">Just link</a>";

echo htmlentities($text); // here it shows up fine in webpage.
file_put_contents($file , $text) or die('Error opening file');
```

Comment: Without htmlentites() whole html tag is being skipped. I want to write to "django unchained.php" file <a href=\"index.php\">Just link</a> exactly. How do I do it?

Comment: @user1392035 Sorry, I missed, that you open the file. Add fclose.

Comment: @user1392035 actually, I suggest you to simplify the code, and not open the same file twice: first, using fopen, then inside file_put_contents. I edited the answer, so it worked better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problems with locks, try this code:

```
$file = 'django unchained.php';
$text = "<a href=\"index.php\">Just link</a>";
file_put_contents($file , $text) or die('Cannot open file for writing');
```

note: you do not need fopen, fclose, htmlspecialchars here